# Dependent qualified name in alias declaration

Tags: c++, c++20

The following [code example](https://godbolt.org/z/PYEbhrjMh) doesn't compile with Clang 15, in contrast to GCC 12.2 and MSVC 19.33. Shouldn't it be okay to omit `typename` here due to its relaxed usage in C++20?

```
template<typename T>    
struct t {
    using v = T::type;
};
```

The error message produced by Clang:

```
<source>:3:15: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'T::type'
    using v = T::type;
              ^~~~~~~
              typename
```

From what I can gather on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names), the keyword `typename` can be omitted in contexts where only a type is expected and this also seems to apply to a dependent name in an alias declaration.

> In some contexts, only type names can validly appear. In these
> contexts, a dependent qualified name is assumed to name a type and no
> typename is required:
>
> ...
>
> • A qualified name that appears in type-id, where the smallest enclosing type-id is:
>     • the type in a new expression that does not parenthesize its type;
>     **• the type-id in an alias declaration;**
>     • a trailing return type,
>     • a default argument of a type template parameter, or
>     • the type-id of a static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast, or reinterpret_cast.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support says the support was added in Clang 16.

Comment: [Clang trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/GnhWs6896) supports this so it's just a lack of this feature.